# Bound on gradient positive harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, harmonic-functions

My question is essentially the same as [An inequality concerning an harmonic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828349/an-inequality-concerning-an-harmonic-function?rq=1) , however I did not find the answer given satisfactory. To restate it, I would like to solve the following:

Let $h$ be a positive harmonic function on $K(0, \rho) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ \vert \ \vert z \vert < \rho \}$. Show that

$$
\vert \nabla h(0) \vert  \leq \frac{2}{\rho} h(0)
$$
and deduce that 
$$
\vert \nabla h(z) \vert \leq \frac{2\rho}{\rho^2- \vert z \vert^2} h(z) \qquad \quad , \vert z \vert < \rho
$$

Showing that $
\vert \nabla h(0) \vert  \leq \frac{2}{\rho} h(0)
$ was rather easy using Harnacks inequality, my issue comes when trying to prove the last bit. Supposedly we should be able to define an automorphism $\varphi: K(0,\rho) \to K(0,\rho)$ such that $\varphi(0)= z$ and hence use the first result on $h \circ \varphi$, since if $\varphi$ is holomorphic $h\circ \varphi$ is again positive harmonic. Now my problem is that I fail to see why doing so wouldn't just imply that

$$
\vert \nabla h(z) \vert  \leq \frac{2}{\rho} h(z)
$$
which is not quite what we want.

Comment: You forgot to apply the chainrule when computing the gradient

Comment: Of course! Doing so gave me the result that I wanted. I don't know how I missed that, but thanks a lot :-)